# Brokered Runtime Component: 'windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer' is invalid according to its datatype

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm attempting to create a [Brokered Windows Runtime Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps) to work with my `UWP` application.

I've been able to build my brokered component and proxy, create the winmd file, and reference the proxy in my `UWP` app. However, in editing the app manifest for the `UWP` application to include the proxy as an extension, I'm encountering the following issue:

> The 'Category' attribute is invalid - The value `windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer` is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/types:ST_ApplicationExtensionCategory_Foundation' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

And here is the XAML code I'm attempting to use in the app manifest:

```
<Extensions>
...
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
        <InProcessServer>
           <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
           <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="BrokeredTasks.Utilities"
                          ThreadingModel="both">
              <ActivatableClassAttribute
                 Name="DesktopApplicationPath"
                 Type="string"
                 Value="C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\Debug\BrokeredTasksProxyStub"/>
           </ActivatableClass>
        </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

#### P.S.

The slightly more readable instructions on using a brokered runtime component along with templates are found [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/10be07b3-67ef-4e02-9243-01b78cd27935) (see Step 9), but **[this tutorial](http://devhawk.net/blog/2014/04/25/brokered-winrt-components-step-one) is the best overall guide** I've found to brokered RT components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that, as someone inexperienced in manually editing app manifests, I confused [`Application/Extensions/Extension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986788.aspx) with [`Package/Extensions/Extension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn934749.aspx).

`inProcessServer` is not a category for an Application `Extension`, but a Package `Extension`.

Thus

```
<Package>
...
    <Application ... >
        <Extensions>
            <!-- Application Extensions here -->
        <Extensions>
    </Application>

    <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
            ...
        </Extension>
    </Extensions>
</Package>
```